# Spring Boot server realistic multipart up/download speed of large (~1GB) files?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, multipartform-data, large-files

I'm working on a **Spring Boot server** which handles up & downloads of **large (~1GB) files** by **multipart** via **HTTP**. I disabled Spring's default multipart filter (by `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false`) and **use [Apache FileUpload Streaming API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html)** to process the HTTP request.
When I start simultaneous uploads (from postman) or downloads (from browser) I get the max **sum** speed of about 40MB/s. The bottleneck looks to be the **CPU**, since it's **~100% utilized (all cores) at 40MB/s** speed.

I tried to profile uploads by discarding the incoming HTTP multipart InputStream in the `@Service` behind the upload `@Controller`, but the 40MB/s limit didn't get faster. *(I mean discarding that I read out the stream but didn't forward it into a file or anything else. So basically just skipped the stream.)*

I get the above performance on an **[Intel i7-6700HQ processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88967/intel-core-i7-6700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html) (4 cores 8 threads ~ 3GHz)**.

I want to know if **I messed up something OR is this the limitation of using Spring Boot?** How could I **improve performance?** Is Spring Boot a bad choice for this task?

*(Here you can see the source code, if you would take a look at it: https://github.com/janosgats/laboschqpa.filehost)*

Comment: What OS are you running on? Can you distinguish between system, user, and I/O CPU usage? Does "100%" mean a single core or all cores? (An application based on Netty might be a better choice here; Spring WebFlux is one choice.)

Comment: It runs in a kubernetes cluster. I also tried it on the host itself (Windows 10), and got the same numbers. The CPU is NOT waiting for IO. 100% means all cores.

Comment: I tried to switch to APR instead of NIO, but it didn't cause any difference.

Comment: Then the only thing I can suggest is full profiling.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to do it in Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes. Start by figuring out exactly what the bottleneck is, which means profiling it. (I also recommend, as I said, trying the WebFlux Netty layer. Servlet NIO is all well and good but still isn't as efficient as `ByteBuffer` for mass transfer.)